# Using rename_function() in PHP (Not working)

Tags: php, function

Maybe I am not understanding the [rename_function();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) function or it's use correctly.

Here is my first experimentation with this function:

```
<?php

rename_function('count', 'contar');

$var = array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
    );

$number = contar($var);
echo $number;

?>
```

As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/SebvR) it doesn't work

When I use it in [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) Chrome gives me this error:

> Server error.
>
> The website encountered an error while
>   retrieving
>   `http://localhost:8888/translate.php`.
>   It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly.

Any ideas why this could be?

Thanks in advance!

BTW: sorry if it is an absolute basic question but I can't figure it out!

Comment: The client side is not where you look for PHP errors. Look in the php error logs in /Applications/MAMP/logs

Comment: Have you installed the APD (Advanced PHP debugger) PECL extension?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know PHP had that. Scary. It'd be a nightmare to debug a script that uses this widely...

Comment: @ceejayoz I just got "randomly curious" and wondered wether it was possible to change a function name, I want to see how it handles errors now, as soon as I have the APD installed!

Comment: @KThompson Sorry I just saw you comment! I cant find that folder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APD package is not installed for your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install pecl package apd
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php